# Insertar datos de una tabla con select de otra en Laravel

Tags: laravel

soy nuevo en Laravel y estoy tratando de hacer una validación para insertar datos en una tabla llamada lote si la cantidad no excede el de la capacidad de la tabla galpon.
[image: Tabla Galpon]

[image: Tabla Lote]

Así que en el controlador para guardar datos intento hacer una validación, sin embargo la información siempre se inserta.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $lotes= new Lote();
    $lotes->galpon_id = $request->get('galpon_id');
    $lotes->fechaingreso = $request->get('fechaingreso');
    $lotes->fechaproduccion = $request->get('fechaproduccion');
    $lotes->cantidad = $request->get('cantidad');
    $lotes->raza = $request->get('raza');
    $lotes->estadoproduccion = $request->get('estadoproduccion');

      $cantidadGalpon = Galpon::select('galpons.capacidad')->
    where('galpons.id'== $lotes->galpon_id);

    if($cantidadGalpon>$lotes->cantidad){
        $lotes->save();
    }
    

    return redirect('/lotes');

}
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar con mi error?
Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda brindada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu código hacen falta algunas cosas que aquí te las agregaré

```
//Aquí te falta agregar el método first() al final (YA TE LO CORRIJO)
$cantidadGalpon = Galpon::select('galpons.capacidad')->where('galpons.id',$lotes->galpon_id)->first();

//y aqui te falta agregar el campo el cual quieres validar
 if($cantidadGalpon->capacidad > $lotes->cantidad){
        $lotes->save();
    }
```

a tu codigo le hacen falta validaciones ya que vas a estar guardando registros siempre y cuando la cantidad sea mayor que la capacidad, pero tienes que ir disminuyendo tu capacidad debido a que con cada inserción el galpon se deberia ir llenando

Comment: Sí resolvió el problema, Gracias.